# How to exclude fields from form prefilled with object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How to exclude some fields from form created in view from instance?
I want to allow users to edit their attributes like username or telephone but in this form, they shouldn't change their password.

I've tried this:

```
del user_profile_form.fields['telephone']
```

But it raises `CSRF token missing or incorrect.` when I do that.

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user.userprofile)

    context = {'user_form': user_form,
               'user_profile_form': user_profile_form}

    return render(request, 'auth/profiles/edit-profile.html', context=context)
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1','password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

        return self.cleaned_data

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('telephone','marital_status','how_do_you_know_about_us')
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='userprofile')

    # ATRIBUTY KTORE BUDE MAT KAZDY
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
            ('coincidence',u'It was coincidence'),
            ('relative_or_friends','From my relatives or friends'),
            )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True)

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single','Single'),
        ('married','Married'),
        ('separated','Separated'),
        ('divorced','Divorced'),
        ('widowed','Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True)

    # OD KIAL STE SA O NAS DOZVEDELI
    # A STAV

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name,self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name,self.user.last_name)
```

**NEW VIEW**

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request)
        if user_form.is_valid() and user_profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            user_profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/logged-in')
        else:
            print user_form.errors
            print user_profile_form.errors

    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user.userprofile)
        temp_user_profile_form = deepcopy(user_profile_form)
        del temp_user_profile_form.fields['password1']
        del temp_user_profile_form.fields['password2']
    context = {'user_form': user_form,
               'user_profile_form': temp_user_profile_form}

    return render(request, 'auth/profiles/edit-profile.html', context=context)
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'password1'
```

Comment: Have you included a `{% csrf_token %}` in your template? If you post your template code, that might be helpful. Also, please post your forms.py code

Comment: @CurtisOlson It was just once and from then, it works - telephone deletion worked, but it raises exception when I try to remove password1 (added code)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're referencing `password1` and `password2` in your `Meta` class for the `UserForm` model form. These should be removed, as they aren't fields in your User model. So after the change, your `UserForm` should be:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # These 2 fields are unbound fields...
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # These fields are your User model's fields
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

You don't need to remove them in the view. Just exclude them in the template.

Additionally, you can make the form fields hidden inputs in the `__init__` method for your form if you'd like. I'd recommend this approach.

Comment: Curtis thanks but this approach didn't exclude password1 nor password2 from edit-profile. It's still there. I've tried to make migrations and migrate, still the same problem.